# How to find in Java the largest value in variable length List with variable length nested Lists index by index?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I have a `List<List<Integer>>` that has an arbitrary number of variable length `List<Integer>`. I need to compare each value at the same index and make sure those values are sorted meaning the first list should be smaller than the next based on index by index values.

In the below example, each index would be compared between the lists at index `i = 0`, the values are all *int 5* so continue. For `i = 1`, the values are all 3, so continue. For `i = 2`, `listA` is larger because it has an additional integer where as the others are null and should return false.

```java
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = List.of(List.of(5, 3, 2),  // A
                                          List.of(5, 3),     // B
                                          List.of(5, 3));    // C
```

Another example. Here, these are not in the correct order because `listB` fails on the last index because `ListA` and `listC` have values as they are not `null`, so `listB` is smaller.

```java
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = List.of(List.of(4, 3, 2, 1),   // A
                                          List.of(4, 3, 2),      // B
                                          List.of(4, 3, 2, 1));  // C
```

In this example, they are in order.

```java
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = List.of(List.of(4, 3),        // A
                                          List.of(4, 3, 1),     // B
                                          List.of(5, 3, 2, 1),  // C
                                          List.of(5, 4, 3));    // D
```

I have tried many options. I have tried to use `Comparator` to create a custom compare method, nested for loops, recursion, etc. I keep running into problems with `IndexOutOfBOundsExceptions` and this is still kind of mind boggling for me. I have been able to sort the lists or find the maximum values of the lists and compare them to the others, but not while maintaining the order.

I feel like pushing each value at the same index onto a stack and then comparing them would be a good solution, but I am having trouble implementing it.

The end result is I need to determine if `List<List<Integer>>` is in proper order from smallest to largest and `return true`; otherwise, `return false`. The last example would be true and the others would be false.

### EDIT

I came up with this and it seems to work.

```java
public class ListTest {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = List.of(List.of(3, 2, 1),     // A
                                                  List.of(4, 3, 1),     // B
                                                  List.of(5, 4, 3));    // C

        boolean correctOrder = true;
        int max = getMaxLength(listOfLists);

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < listOfLists.size(); j++) {
                try {
                    stack.push(listOfLists.get(j).get(i));
                } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                    stack.push(0);
                }
            }

            if (!isSorted(stack)) {
                correctOrder = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(correctOrder);
    }

    public static boolean isSorted(Stack<Integer> stack) {
        int temp = stack.pop();

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            int compare = stack.pop();

            if (temp < compare)
                return false;

            temp = compare;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static int getMaxLength(List<List<Integer>> list) {
        int maxLength = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).size() > maxLength) {
                maxLength = list.get(i).size();
                System.out.println(maxLength);
            }
        }

        return maxLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: From all your unsuccessful tries, pick up your consider the closest to you goal and use [Edit] to add this code to your question.

Comment: What result are you trying to get?

Comment: I edited it to add what I am trying to accomplish. I need to check if the list is in the correct order (smallest to largest) based on the examples I provided.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're trying to do.  You obviously can't compare the lists by elements because they don't contain the same number of elements.  Do you just want to arrange the outer list by the size of the inner lists?  e.g.  what do you mean by, "List<List<Integer>> is in proper order", what should the order be?

Comment: I don't need to rearrange the contents. I just need to check that each list is in a proper order. The first list must be smaller than the next.[[1],[2],[3]] = true.

[[1,2],[1],[1]] = false, [[1,2],[1],[2]] = true

Comment: bad title "find in Java the largest value" - how does that relate to the body "make sure those values are sorted"  ??

Comment: *"[[1,2],[1],[2]] = true"* - Then why did you accept an answer that doesn't do that? Where's the mistake? In the example or in the accepting?

Comment: @KellyBundy I am not sure what you mean. It works for me. list[2][0] is larger than list[0][0] and list[1][0].

Comment: @thelinuxfan That answer says the second list is smaller than the first and third list. So it doesn't result in "true" as it should according to you.

Comment: @KellyBundy Ahh I see. I messed up when I wrote it. That should be false and it works as I intended just not how I wrote it :)

Comment: Ok. But to be sure, what should the result be for [[1,2],[3]]?

Comment: true. I see. The accepted answer gives false when len 1 in second list. In my testing and application, I would only ever have len 2 as it would be [[1,2],[3,0]]. You are right and thank you for catching that.

Comment: You're really just asking for ordinary lexicographic order then, aren't you?

Comment: Yes. It would be in reverse lexicographic order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you need a comparator. This is pretty easy. Just create two separate comparators: first should sort lists by size, second - by content.

```java
public static Comparator<List<Integer>> createComparator() {
    Comparator<List<Integer>> sortBySizeAsc = Comparator.comparingInt(List::size);
    Comparator<List<Integer>> sortByContentAsc = (one, two) -> {
        Iterator<Integer> it1 = one.iterator();
        Iterator<Integer> it2 = two.iterator();

        while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
            int res = Integer.compare(it1.next(), it2.next());

            if (res != 0)
                return res;
        }

        return 0;
    };
    return sortBySizeAsc.thenComparing(sortByContentAsc);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could sort a copy of your lists acording to your order definition and check if the copy and original are equal. (Might be not the efficient way to do if your list are very big).

```
static boolean areListsInOrder(List<List<Integer>> listOfLists){
    //a comparator to sort your lists comparing each value index wise, then comparing by list size
    Comparator<List<Integer>> comp = (list1,list2) -> IntStream.range(0, Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size()))
                                                               .map(i -> list1.get(i).compareTo(list2.get(i)))
                                                               .dropWhile( i -> i == 0).findFirst()
                                                               .orElse(Integer.compare(list1.size(), list2.size()));

    //copy your list and sort
    List<List<Integer>> copy = new ArrayList<>(listOfLists);
    copy.sort(comp);

    //check if the sorted and original are equal
    return copy.equals(listOfLists);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood what you're trying to achieve, below should be the solution:

```java
boolean checkListsOrder(List<List<Integer>> listOfLists) {
    int maxSize = 0;
    for (List<Integer> singleList : listOfLists)
        maxSize = maxSize > singleList.size() ? maxSize : singleList.size();

    Map<Integer, Integer> checkIfAllValuesEqualsAndWrongOrdered = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfLists.size(); i++)
        checkIfAllValuesEqualsAndWrongOrdered.put(i, 0);

    for (int j = 0; j < maxSize; j++) {
        TreeMap<Integer, Integer> orderOfValues = new TreeMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfLists.size(); i++) {
            if (j < listOfLists.get(i).size()) {
                orderOfValues.put(i, listOfLists.get(i).get(j));
            }
        }

        Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> previousEntry = orderOfValues.firstEntry();
        Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> nextEntry = orderOfValues.higherEntry(previousEntry.getKey());
        while (nextEntry != null) {
            if (previousEntry.getValue() > nextEntry.getValue())
                return false;
            else if (previousEntry.getValue() == nextEntry.getValue() && listOfLists.get(previousEntry.getKey()).size() > listOfLists.get(nextEntry.getKey()).size()) {
                if (checkIfAllValuesEqualsAndWrongOrdered.get(nextEntry.getKey()) + 1 == listOfLists.get(nextEntry.getKey()).size() - 1)
                    return false;
                else
                    checkIfAllValuesEqualsAndWrongOrdered.put(nextEntry.getKey(), checkIfAllValuesEqualsAndWrongOrdered.get(nextEntry.getKey()) + 1);
            }
            previousEntry = nextEntry;
            nextEntry = orderOfValues.higherEntry(nextEntry.getKey());
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I probably did not explain my problem well enough. I apologize if that is the case. This is showing [[3,2,1],[5,4,3],[5,4,2]] as true when it should be false. 

What is compare() overriding?